# How to write the callback function of a telegram bot for the job queue?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, job-queue

I'm confused about this [job queue](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) thing. In the callback function I want to get access to the users message and work on it but in the article says that the call back accepts only bot and job parameters. with those in hand I can not get access to the `update.message.text`. So for example I want to rewrite the following function as a callback one which I can't figure it out:

```
def echo(bot,update):
    if tldextract.extract(update.message.text).registered_domain:
        bot.send_message(chat_id= update.message.chat_id, text="OK")
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the context when you create the job.

You can read from the example [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) near the bottom of the page:

```
>>> from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
>>> def callback_alarm(bot, job):
...     bot.send_message(chat_id=job.context, text='BEEP')
...
>>> def callback_timer(bot, update, job_queue):
...     bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
...                      text='Setting a timer for 1 minute!')
... 
...     job_queue.run_once(callback_alarm, 60, context=update.message.chat_id)
...
>>> timer_handler = CommandHandler('timer', callback_timer, pass_job_queue=True)
>>> u.dispatcher.add_handler(timer_handler)
```

You can pass anything (including telegram objects, list/dicts, etc) into the job's `context` when you use the `run_once`, `run_daily` and `run_repeating` functions. Then in your callback function you must pass 2 parameters as you said, `bot` and `job`, then get the data you need by accessing `job.context`.

Comment: in the example the chat_id is passed only. How can I pass several items into it?

Comment: You can pass anything, for example the whole update: `context=update`, or a dict you created: `context={"chat_id": update.message.chat_id, "text": update.message.text, "custom_stuff": "some other text"}` or actually anything you would like to pass, treat them as normal python variables is okay; 
 then you can get it in your callback function with: `update = job.context`, `stuff = job.context["custom_stuff"]`, etc.